# Display database query via foreach in view

Tags: codeigniter-2

Please tell me how do I echo a foreach loops in view page called admin.php and look similar to a blog posting ? I’ve been asking around and have failed to figure this out.

CONTROLLER FUNCTION :

```
<?php

class Callback extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->model('blogpost');
        $this->load->library('javascript');

    }   

    public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM post;");

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
               echo $row['id'];
               echo $row['posts'];
               echo html_entity_decode ($row['content']);
        }
         $this->load->view('admin',$row);
    }

}
```

VIEW PAGE :

`foreach` ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your program is simply echoing your database data before the view is even loaded. That's probably not what you're looking for.

You could simply pass your raw data to your view:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM post;");
$data = array('rows' => $query->result_array());
$this->load->view('admin', $data);
```

Now you've sent your data to your view which will be available in the `$rows` variable inside your view.

Now, in your view file:

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['posts'];
    echo html_entity_decode ($row['content']);
}
```

See the "Adding Dynamic Data to the View" section of the [CodeIgniter docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Comment: Thanks ! The answer was there all along. I just need to add php tag before & after the foreach. LOL!